# Does bound service using messenger will run even after the Activity(client) gets killed

Tags: android, service, messenger

I am having a problem with the bound service. In short i am building an app which calculates the distance, time and calories burnt for a marathon run. So my app should run on background. I implemented messenger service. I have started the service using startforeground with ongoing notification. I am using messenger because I have to updated the data in UI. But when my activity(Client) gets destroyed. My service also gets destroyed. Is any other way to run the service indefinetly. Please help deadline is too near.

Comment: start your service first, then bind to the started serice, btw there is no need to use messenger, use local bound service instead

Comment: you can also use AIDL instead of Messenger API

Comment: @pskink does aidl is powerful than messenger ? .Both are used for interprocess  communication only .

Comment: AIDL is **much** easier to use